# # Could not dump table "subscriptions" because of following NoMethodError # undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, migration, schema

I started a new project:

I have only run the following commands:

```
rails g model subscription
```

Then:

```
rails g controller subscriptions
```

Then:

added `resources :subscriptions` to my routes

Then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then:

```
rails g migration add_column_to_subscriptions
```

with the following content:

```
class AddColumnsToSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration

      def change
        add_column :subscriptions, :fname, :text
        add_column :subscriptions, :lname, :text
        add_column :subscriptions, :email, :email
      end
    end
```

Then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

My schema had a subscriptions table in there before I did the add columns migration. but now in the schema I have:

```
# Could not dump table "subscriptions" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What happened here? None of the solutions on SO I found were useful to me / or I did not understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this error is still happening for you, but if it does for someone else. The problem is that your database is probably in a funky state, with a wrong column type, in this case 'email' I guess. Try to change it to string and start again.

```
class AddColumnsToSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :subscriptions, :fname, :string
    add_column :subscriptions, :lname, :string
    add_column :subscriptions, :email, :string
  end
end
```

Also, I'd recommend to use string for first and last name as they'll probably never be more than 256 characters. It'll make your DB a bit more efficient. It worked for me so maybe it can help someone else who end up there.